# Rails - get records that match a particular wday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

Trying to find records on a particular day then adding a field together.

```
days = 7.times

  days.each do |day|
    today = Date::DAYNAMES[day]
    @dailysheets = @timesheet.sheets.where(:date.strftime("%A") == today)
    @dailyhours =+ @dailysheets.sum(:hours)
  end
```

Problem is I cant use .strftime in the where condition...

Is there a way to refactor this to work?

Comment: You probably shouldn't. You're turning one query into seven queries. You should load all the records (assuming it's a reasonably small set of records) and partition them in Ruby.

Comment: would love to know an alternative? the reason i am doing it 7 times is so I can check for records on each day if there is more than one then it combines them together. this part is not so relevant as that will change = @dailyhours =+ @dailysheets.sum(:hours) but finding the records for each day is the issue here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use a database specific function to achieve what you're looking for. Using Postgres you can achieve what you're looking for by doing the following:

`@timesheet.sheets.where("to_char(date, 'day') = ?", Date.today.strftime('%A').downcase)`

Since you will be manually creating a SQL string, you should be sure to prefix the column name with the appropriate table name in order to avoid column name collisions should there be other tables joined in the query.

Comment: I get an error as a timesheet has many sheets through timesheet_rows. I get the error

PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: function char_at(date, unknown) does not exist LINE 1: ..." WHERE "timesheet_rows"."timesheet_id" = $1 AND (char_at(da... ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. : SELECT "sheets".* FROM "sheets" INNER JOIN "timesheet_rows" ON "sheets"."id" = "timesheet_rows"."sheet_id" WHERE "timesheet_rows"."timesheet_id" = $1 AND (char_at(date, 'day') = 'Sunday')

Comment: Whoops, apologies. It should be `to_char(date, "day")`. Fixed above.